# Spring boot project in Heroku as dependency to another local Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heroku, dependencies

I have a Spring Boot project(say A) that is deployed in Heroku. I am currently creating another Spring Boot project(say L) which is dependent on A. I am creating these as Gradle projects. I see the procedure of making dependency on two projects in Local and those were Maven projects.

I need to place the Gradle link of A project in the Gradle file of L to access all the contents from A in L. Could anyone suggest me the procedure or any websites that I could look for?

Answer (score 0):

Project A should be structured in a way that it can publish it's shareable components as a library to a [Maven repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories) such as [Central](https://search.maven.org/) or an [internal](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository) company repository.

So project A's directory structure may look like:

```
.
├── shareable-logic
└── src
```

- `src/` is the main Spring Boot application.
- `shareable-logic` is a [subproject](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) that is [published](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Then project B simply needs to depend on the published artifact:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.example:shareable-logic:1.0.0")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have seen the Multi-project Builds article but it looks brand new to me. Could you please help me with any sample projects for reference? That will help me with some good understanding too.